# c++ iterator of type

Tags: c++, iterator

I have to write a container template class that has a const iterator, but I have to make it so that it is actually an stl container's iterator which I refer to as a template parameter.

```
template <typename T, class StoreT = std::vector<T>> 
class Store {
    StoreT data;
public:
    StoreT::const_iterator begin() {return data.begin()}
    StoreT::const_iterator end() {return data.end()}
    //other stuff
};
```

it is called this way:

```
Store<Foo>::const_iterator it1, it2;
    for (it1 = t1.begin(), it2 = t2.begin(); it1 != t1.end(); ++it1,++it2)
        cout<<*it1<<*it2; //just an example
```

I get lots of errors, and I can't figure out how should I make it work. I need to make it for school, in five hours. Any help would be much appreciated.
What is wrong, and what should I do to make it work?

Comment: What errors do you get? Please provide a [mcve] and include the full error output.

Comment: `typename StoreT::const_iterator begin()` since  `StoreT` is a dependent name.  Same for `end()`.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't yet provided a complete error dump, and your posted code is clearly an excerpt, so I'm going point out some things that might already be looked after.

Ensure you're including vector and iostream.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
```

You're explicitly providing the std namespace when you reference vector, but not when you use cout. Do you have a "using namespace std;" somewhere that makes this possible? If not, then you need

```
std::cout<<*it1<<*it2; //just an example
```

Store doesn't yet define const_iterator, so your definitions of it1 and it2 are not valid. You need either a typedef or using statement in the public section of Store:

```
public:
using const_iterator = typename StoreT::const_iterator;
```

Also, you're missing the typename keyword and some semi-colons.

```
typename StoreT::const_iterator begin() {return data.begin();}
typename StoreT::const_iterator end() {return data.end();}
```

Can I assume t1 and t2 are both defined somewhere?